# Android Picture in Picture Potrait Mode

Tags: android, kotlin, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

I am trying to implement Picture in Picture mode but so far as per the example given the only orientation I see is landscape mode.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture

I am trying to have a functionally similar to the WhatsApp app. When the user accepts a call and enters picture in picture mode the window is shown in portrait mode so the user can see the other person well. Will appreciate thoughts on how I can implement this.

```
override fun onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode: Boolean,
                                           newConfig: Configuration) {
    if (isInPictureInPictureMode) {
        // Hide the full-screen UI (controls, etc.) while in picture-in-picture mode.
    } else {
        // Restore the full-screen UI.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [enterPictureInPictureMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#enterPictureInPictureMode(android.app.PictureInPictureParams)) to configure the PIP window.

To have a portrait PIP window use an aspect ratio of ~2/3. (The aspect ratio must be between 0,42 and 2,39.)

```
override fun onUserLeaveHint() {
    enterPictureInPictureMode(PictureInPictureParams.Builder()
            .setAspectRatio(Rational(2, 3))
            .build())
}
```

Example:

[image: pip-example]